# How to get a select quantity of products from a WooCommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on a WordPress project where I'm using WooCommerce. I'm trying to make a form that the customers can use to refund their orders, and I'm pretty far in right now. One thing that I am trying to solve is, is it possible to let the customer select how many of select products they want to return?

Below I've used WooCommerce's own  functions to print the selected order's information. Here I would like to add an possible input which lets the customer select the amount of items they want to return, but I am not sure how.

Also for context: This is the second page which shows the user what items he has ordered with this order. On the first page the customer was asked their info to make sure it's their order. On the third and final page the user is sure that they want to make the refund request, and if they want to leave a comment.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $ordernumber );
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $unitprice = $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity();
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" .$item->get_name() . "|" . $item->get_quantity() . "|" . $item->get_total() ."'>";
    echo '<p>';
    echo __('Tuotteen nimi: ' ) . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
    if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
        echo "Määrä: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty' value='" . $item->get_quantity() . "'max='" .$item->get_quantity() . "' min='0' > " . "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo __('Määrä: ' ) . $item->get_quantity() . '<br>';
    }
    if ($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
        echo __('Tuotteen kappalehinta: ') . $unitprice . '€' . '<br/>';
    }
    echo __('Tuotteiden kokonaishinta: ' )  . wc_price($item->get_total()) . '</p>' . '<br/>';
}
echo '<p>'. __('Tilauksen yhteishinta: ') . $order->get_total() . '</p>';
```

If there's anyone who could even at least point me at the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can see you have input box for quantify, so you want it to be changed to select box, instead of typical input box ?

Comment: @cjmling Both of these work, I just thought an input would be the easiest :P

Comment: @cjmling And the problem I mean was that, I am not able to let the user SELECT the amount they want since the current input you see here doesn't work.